# Auto Rewind Live Video Stream On Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, jwplayer

I have the following code for my 4 jwPlayers set in place currently. It will rewind ALL 4 players 60 seconds on button click. This works great.

How would I edit this to auto rewind 60 seconds on page load so that when the video starts the DVR and auto seeks -60 seconds and no button is needed to be pressed. It just automatically loads on a 60 sec delay.

I tried this but no luck. Any help with fixing the code to achieve this would be great!

```html
<input type="button" value="Pause" onClick="jwplayer('video1').pause(true);jwplayer('video2').pause(true);;jwplayer('video3').pause(true);;jwplayer('video4').pause(true);;" style="background:rgba(192,192,192,0.3);color:white;font-weight:bold" name="button2">
```

```js
jwplayer("video4").onBeforePlay(function() {
  var position = jwplayer('video1').getPosition();
  position -= 60;
  jwplayer('video1').seek(position);;
  
  var position = jwplayer('video3').getPosition();
  position -= 60;
  jwplayer('video3').seek(position);;
  
  var position = jwplayer('video4').getPosition();
  position -= 60;
  jwplayer('video4').seek(position);;
  
  var position = jwplayer('video2').getPosition();
  position -= 60;
  jwplayer('video2').seek(position);;
});
```

Player code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="3SYLbRo6MN5cBDxwpZh3dl1gb0lMTUOos31M5hoAlf4=";</script>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                // jwplayer.key="sXW0XA1MksiJ6hYVNHKJFCtOB4qTihu2B0xyTyZoMiA=";
                jwplayer.key = 'sXW0XA1MksiJ6hYVNHKJFCtOB4qTihu2B0xyTyZoMiA=';</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapvideo">
    <div id='video1'></div> 
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script src='//static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-de7e2ef6bfefd24b79a3f68b414b87b8db5b08439cac3f1012092b2290c719cd.js'></script>
<script >var playerInstance = jwplayer("video1");
playerInstance.setup({ skin: {
          "name": "alaska",
          "url": ""
        },
logo: {
          "file": "",
          "position": "top-right",
          "hide": "false",
        },
         
                    'file': "DVR m3u8 here",
                    'title': '',
                    'aspectratio': '16:9',
                    stretching: 'exactfit',
                    'bufferlength': '5',
                    'height': '126px',
                    'width': '624px',
                    'primary': 'hls',
                    'sharing':'false',
                    'controls':'false',
                    'autostart': 'true',
                    'wmode': 'opaque',
                    'image': '',
                    'abouttext': '',
                    'aboutlink': ''
                });



 
</script>
</div
```

> 

Comment: Why would you need to auto-seek -60 seconds on page load? The video will play from the start, you can't go back any further than that. More detail is needed here.

Comment: Also, avoid putting `onclick` attributes in your HTML, and if you do have to use them, just call a function - don't put that much JS in there.

Comment: thats what im trying to figure out i want it to happen automatically not on click but i cant get it figured out and because its a DVR stream that starts from "live" but  i want it to rewind 60 seconds on page load to be on a delay the DVR is 24 hrs but i just want it to auto rewind 60 seconds from the "live" position

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i added the player code

Comment: Thank you - now it makes sense given that it's a live video stream

Comment: Yes i am wanting this pretty much in -60 but i cant figire out how to set it up with my player :/ https://demos.jwplayer.com/linking-to-time-offset/#t=30

Comment: @user19500487 If still not solved... You can't do it on page load. You rewind when video is loaded. You need to add an event listener to the JW Player for a "loaded" event then try a rewind. I dont use JW Player but you can research how it to add event listeners. For practicing, I would use only 1 video player to test rewinding.